# Parsing Through XML Files with Selected Keywords

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, keyword

I have the below code. Supposed, a user can insert 1-4 keywords and click search button, then there will be results showing the whole `<item></item>` in the richtextbox if the content in sub-tag `<description</description>` contain one/more of the keywords entered. But the code is not right at this line `if (itemDescription.Contains(txtComKeyword1 | txtComKeyword2 | txtComKeyword3 | txtComKeyword4)`.

Please could you guys take a look at it? Your help is much appreciated! Thank you.

The below is part of my XML file structure:

```
<item>
      <title>[PhoTosynthesIs] Being driven</title>
      <author>PhoTosynthesIs</author>
      <description>purely by profit, I've decided to stick to my strategy and exit both tranches at 177. Will pick this stock up again when it breaches and holds the next pivot point. gl all</description>
      <link>http://www.lse.co.uk/shareChat.asp?ShareTicker=BARC&amp;post=5660817</link>
      <pubDate>Wed, 08 Aug 2012 11:43:17 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
<item>
      <title>[b36m] alw51</title>
      <author>b36m</author>
      <description>Could you share your thoughts/opinions  on a buy in price based on TW with me please   many thanks</description>
      <link>http://www.lse.co.uk/shareChat.asp?ShareTicker=BARC&amp;post=5660636</link>
      <pubDate>Wed, 08 Aug 2012 11:16:56 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
```

The below is my piece of code for this function:

```
private void searchComByKeywords()
{
    // Process the list of files found in the directory. 
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); //* create an xml document object.

            string docPath = fileName;

            xmlDoc.Load(docPath); //* load the XML document from the specified file.

            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("item");

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {

                XmlElement itemElement = (XmlElement)node;

                string itemDescription = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("description")[0].InnerText;

                if (itemDescription.Contains(txtComKeyword1 | txtComKeyword2 | txtComKeyword3 | txtComKeyword4)
                {
                    string itemTitle = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("title")[0].InnerText;
                    string itemDate = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].InnerText;
                    string itemAuthor = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("author")[0].InnerText;

                    richComResults.AppendText("Author: " + itemAuthor + "\nDate: " + itemDate + "\nTitle: " + itemTitle + "\nDescription: " + itemDescription + "\n\n--------\n\n");
                }
                //else
                //{
                //    richComResults.AppendText("There is no author " + txtComAuthor.Text.ToString().ToLower() + ". Please ensure you are using a correct author name.");
                //}
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try:

```
if (itemDescription.Contains(txtComKeyword1) || itemDescription.Contains(txtComKeyword2) || itemDescription.Contains(txtComKeyword3) || itemDescription.Contains(txtComKeyword4))
{
...
}
```

Comment: I did this: `if (txtComKeyword1.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword1.Text.ToLower()) || txtComKeyword2.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword2.Text.ToString()) || txtComKeyword3.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword3.Text.ToString()) || txtComKeyword4.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword4.Text.ToString()))` and it works. :) But it seems very long code.

Answer (score 0):

When the condition in `if` statement is complicated and its meaning is not immediately clear, I tend to refactor it into a separate method. In your case, it could look like the following:

```
private static bool DoesItemDescriptionContainOneOf(string description, params string[] items)
{
    return items.Any(description.Contains);
}
```

Then, your condition will look like this:

```
if (DoesItemDescriptionContainOneOf(itemDescription, txtComKeyword1, txtComKeyword2, txtComKeyword3, txtComKeyword4))
{
    ....
}
```

A lot neater, eh?

Comment: It looks neat, but I don't really understand how do I apply it as I got a red line under the term `Any` and the whole `if` statement that line. I am very very new to C# like since 2 weeks ago. :|

Comment: @Shyuan `Any` is an extension method that lives in namespace `System.Linq`. Add an using directive for this namespace (i.e. `using System.Linq;`) to the top of your file and it will work. I recommend reading more about extension methods and LINQ - often, they will really simplify your code.

Comment: Hi Nikola, the `Any` issue is fixed but the if statement still showing red line under `DoesItemDescriptionContainOneOf(itemDescription, txtComKeyword1, txtComKeyword2, txtComKeyword3, txtComKeyword4)`. Do you have idea what's going on? The error says it has some invalid arguments. Thanks.

Comment: @Shyuan `txtComKeyword` parameters must be of type `string`. From your comment to tanathos's answer, I can see that they are probably textboxes.